# Using _stdcall will change name of exported functions in dll

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, export

I am trying to make module (dll) for `Profilab`. For that to work, there should be a list of exported names, to example

```
// return number of inputs
unsigned char NumInputs()
```

when looking at examples for `C++ Builder`, it's declared like this

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char _stdcall NumInputs();
```

when I declare it same way in Visual Studio 2013 Express (?) C++ project, I am getting name exported like this (checked with dependency walker):

```
_NumInputs@0
```

Which doesn't works for `Profilab`.

Removing `_stdcall` part will generate proper name (`NumImputs`), but software will crash and I think is due to missing `_stdcall` part.

What should I do? How to export `NumInputs` and have `_stdcall` at same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function with the right calling convention (stdcall).

Thus, you won't get a crash.

Still, you also need the right names or it won't link, so [use a def-file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx) which explicitly lists which function shall be exported using what name (if any) and/or specified ordinal.

```
LIBRARY   BTREE
EXPORTS
   Insert   @1
   Delete   @2
   Member   @3
   Min   @4
```

This example was copied from the linked documentation. All the export statements follow this pattern:

```
entryname[=internalname] [@ordinal [NONAME]] [[PRIVATE] | [DATA]]
```

Comment: What is ABI? How can I define a name of function in def-file? If I understand correctly, names are already in obj-files, there was even statement what with "__declspec(dllexport)" def-files become obsolete. Could you please extend your answer a bit? To example, changing name from "_NumInputs@0" into "NumInputs".

Comment: I created def-file, added it to the project and set [linker option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34c30xs1.aspx). It works now, thanks!